# App got reject because of enable illegal file sharing

Tags: iphone

I have an app that allow people to store any type of file and transfer files between computer and iphone through wifi. After few days of review Apple reject my app because

> 22.4: Apps that enable illegal file sharing will be rejected

1. I was wondering that how come I can still find a lot of app that do the same way as my app do and got passed?
2. Apple allow developer to turn on iTunes file sharing, isn't this the same concept as transfer file through wifi? the different is wireless.
3. I am not able to control user to not transfer illegal file.

Is there any way to get pass this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add some kind of license agreement that the user has to accept before being able to use this app (i.e. "you are not allowed to use this app for illegal file sharing").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can appeal the decision. Or perhaps there would be a way to appease Apple, maybe by warning users against distributing copyright material before opening the connection?

Bottom line is, the only way to know for sure is to ask Apple. For better or worse, they are the gatekeepers; we can only speculate.

Comment: I am contacting Apple for solution.

Answer (score -2):

No, Apple is a dictatorship. But Google isn't better at all. The app will get online but gets removed after a competitor sent an DMCA notice (without a valid reason, just wild accusations). Ask the mupen64plus-ae developer